# Logs for the communication between Kube API server and ETCD

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I am trying to understand the internal communication in the cluster for example when creating a pod.

```
root@kmaster-0:# kubectl -v=7 -n mynamespace run mypod --image=nginx
I0903 11:01:06.368969  594516 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /root/.kube/config
I0903 11:01:06.372708  594516 round_trippers.go:432] POST https://192.168.178.111:6443/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods?fieldManager=kubectl-run
```

The verbose output of kubectl shows the http requests sent to the api-server, so i wanted to check what the api-server do, but the logs of the api-server are not showing anything related to the created pod or requests sent to ETCD. The logs only show the following

```
root@kmaster-0:~# kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-apiserver-kmaster-0
I0903 11:00:52.122893       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0903 11:00:57.184420       1 controller.go:611] quota admission added evaluator for: namespaces
I0903 11:01:27.124960       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0903 11:01:27.125577       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0903 11:01:27.125838       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0903 11:02:11.820307       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0903 11:02:11.820465       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0903 11:02:11.820892       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0903 11:02:42.852719       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0903 11:02:42.852810       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0903 11:02:42.852833       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
```

I was hoping to find the logs of the communication with the etcd and scheduler for example.
Is there any logs for the communication between the api-server and the control plane components ?

Comment: As far as I know, all of the control plane components also honor `--v=` flags, but I don't know that they're going to log _traffic_ as you're requesting. Turning up the similar verbosity of the `etcd` daemons might get you closer, or the ultimate end of recompiling etcd to log what you want

Comment: when i add --v=9 to the kube-apiserver, i got indeed more information, but the apiserver still doesn't show logs related to putting objects in the etcd server